# what is the data type of user in Firebase Sign In User Authentication Callback Result

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new in programming in swift. I am trying to refactor my code, to look more readable.

after successfully login using google account and logged in to firebase authentication. I want to save user basic information using `UserDefaults`, and that action will be performed by `saveUserUsingUserDefault(user: USER)` method that will grab the user result from firebase Authentication.

but when I wrote the method, I need to know the data type of the user

```
func saveUserUsingUserDefault(_ user: iDontKnowWhatDataTypeShouldBeUsedInHere ) {}
```

I have tried to jump to definition in Xcode, but I stuck, I don't know what data type that I should use. I can't find the data type. I can't read a code in objective C as well. here the code which I used.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (USER, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("failed to create firebase user using google account")
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    print("user successfully logged into firebase")

    saveUserUsingUserDefault(user: USER)
    self.login()
}

func saveUserUsingUserDefault(_ user: iDontKnowWhatDataTypeShouldBeUsedInHere ) {
    //Save User basic information using User Default Data Persistance
    let basicUserInformation = [
            "fullname" : user.displayName,
            "email" : user?.email,
            "city" : ""
        ]

    UserDefaults.standard.set(basicUserInformation, forKey: "basicUserInformation")

    // assign the value to superglobal variable 'userInformation' in AppDelegate
    userInformation = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "basicUserInformation") as? [String:Any]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase already have its own way to get currentUser by default so you don't need to save in user default. On top of that too, saving the current User in user default is not recommended for best practice. In Firebase Auth you can get the currentUser by:

```
let auth = Auth.auth()
let currentUser = auth.currentUser
```

The currentUser type that returned by calling currentUser property in auth will be returned in type of User (Firebase User Type) it will have displayName, uid, email, and everything you need by default.

I normally create my own FirbaseController to handle all the Firebase stuff and create getCurrentUser() method inside.